# What is a "3D mouse pad"?

Tags: mouse

I've been looking into getting a new mouse pad, [anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime) style of cause since I'm an [otaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku) and a lot are those ones where they oversize the breasts to use as cushions, not really my style.

While looking on [eBay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBay) I found *[Broccoli Baka and Test 3D Mouse Pad 735](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/160936428351?ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649)*.

I don't know what "3D mouse pad" means, and I tried sending a message to the seller, but I never got a reply.

What is a "3D mouse pad", and are there (if any) problems in using one with a laser mouse?

Comment: I've seen mouse pads filled with liquid and small plastic parts inside (looking like swimming fish). I've also seen silicone-filled hand rests on mouse pads. But I can't say for sure if that's what the seller is talking about.

Comment: A Google Image search for "3d mouse pad" is "interesting" to say the least ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg assume that is what the seller is talking about, is there any potential problems with using a laser mouse with it. also, i would assume you probably saw all the anime style one with the inflated breasts to use as cushions

Comment: Well, as long as the cushions are only used as hand rests, I don't see any problem. But I have no first-hand experiences with mouse pads like these. But the pad you linked above doesn't look like it would have a hand rest. If there are cushions located near the body of the girl in the print, that would be rather uncomfortable to use I'd imagine :\ Sorry that I can't be of more assistance.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg don't worry about it

Comment: 3D could refer to a parallax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax type 3d picture, where there is a lenticular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_lens  lens on top of one of the verticle interlaced pictures http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5184/5783524425_a057be6628_b.jpg. Like what you might get in a cracker jacks box. IF it was that style, the raised lines actually help sliding the mouse around with less drag.

Comment: True laser mice work on most surfaces, so I would expect it to work on that...  Still, $37 for a mouse pad seems a bit extreme

Comment: @Keltari well it's eBay and the seller allows email so the price has to account for the fees, also, it's an image of a girl, not in a bakini (suck it Soul) and doesn't have breast cushions, do you think that they would be common considering the alternative?

Comment: from the looks of it, its just textured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one...the breasts are filled with silicone and feel "Real". It is quite comfortable to rest your wrist on them and it reduces carpel tunnel type muscle strain. I prefer a Tt eSports Dasher silk covered mousepad  over this though.

Comment: i know about those pads however the one in the link isn't one of those, i purposely avoid the ones your talking about cause i feel uncomfortable resting my hand on their breasts like that, seems wrong to me

Comment: It's pretty funny, since they're actually pretty good mousepads because of the breast cushions, or more specifically because each breast is a separate cushion instead of one wide cushion that your wrist just sort of sits on for no benefit. I've had one of those mousepads so long one of the poor girl's breasts is falling out.

Comments you never expected to write on SuperUser #8347